# Find if string is contained in a column of the same mysql table

Tags: mysql, search

I need to get the results from a table where a record is either set to not exclude it or to exclude it if the condition is met. I've searched here for solutions and came up with the following code but the query always returns both records. Here is the basic table with two entries. The way I expect the query to work is to return the first record, since the apply_method is 0, and not return the second record, since the apply_method is 1 and 7 is in the restrict_to column. Would someone explain what I am missing, please?

```
   table (
   name text,
   apply_method int,
   restrict_to text
   )
   name ='name1',
   apply_method = 0
   restrict_to = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'

   name ='name2',
   apply_method = 1
   restrict_to = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'

select
  name
from table
where ( 
  apply_method='0' or (
    apply_method='1' 
    and '7' not in (select restrict_to from table) 
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deal with the comma-separated string of values, use [MySQL's string function `FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) with a `NOT`.

```
SELECT name
FROM t
WHERE apply_method = 0
  OR (apply_method = 1 AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(7, restrict_to))
```

[Here it is in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90a1a5/3)

Ideally, the `restrict_to` values should be expressed in a separate table with a one-to-many relationship with the primary key of your table. `FIND_IN_SET()` may not be performant enough as your table grows.

Consider creating a second table with two columns only. In place of `name`, use whatever real world column is the primary key of your example table.

```
-- table restrictions
name, restrict_to
name1, 1
name1, 2
name1, 3
name1, 4
name1, 5
name1, 6
name1, 7
name2, 1
name2, 2
name2, 3
name2, 4
name2, 5
name2, 6
name2, 7
```

And query it with a `LEFT JOIN`.  This will allow MySQL to join on indexed columns rather than doing string searches for every row. It could be far faster on a large table.

```
SELECT t.name
FROM
  table t
  -- Join on the common column and the value you want to restrict
  LEFT JOIN restrictions ON t.name = restrictions.name AND restrict_to = 7
WHERE
  apply_method = 0
  -- A NULL in the left join indicates a non-existing row
  OR (apply_method = 1 AND restrictions.name IS NULL)
```

Comment: The first solution failed for some reason but the second worked well. Since that will be quicker, I will use it. Thank you for posting the solution.